# jQuery append() unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is an example of the array I am going to fetch:

```
[
    {"code":"001","name":"FOO","icon":"foo.png","price":3.5},
    {"code":"002","name":"BAR","icon":"bar.png","price":4.5}
]`
```

The DOM I have to fill looks like:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:0;">     
    <ul id="#list">     
    </ul>
</div>
```

The JS code that fills in everything is:

```
function exampleGet() {

$.getJSON("/myfile.json", function(jsonResponse) {

    var counter = 0,
        content = '',
        listStart = '<li><div class="slide"><table class="spoon"><tr>',
        listEnd = '</tr></table></div></li>',
        columnStart = '<td><div class="spoon-banner"><ul>',
        columnEnd = '</ul></div></td>';     

    for (i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {

        var lStart = '',
            lEnd = '',
            // string that contains HTML and array values, accessed
            // by: jsonResponse[i].key
            colContent = [...string with HTML...]

        // makes sure to group everything 4 by 4
        if(counter === 0) {  
            lStart = listStart;
        }                                                                      
        // makes sure to group everything 4 by 4
        if(counter === 3) {
            lEnd = listEnd;
            counter = -1;
        }

        // use an unique string for all changes
        content = content.concat(lStart,columnStart,coinLogo,coinData,columnEnd,lEnd);                        
        counter++;
    };

    $('#list').append(content);
});
}
```

**RESULT**

The "respose" tab of Mozilla Developers Tools shows an (apparently) random string (see below) and no changes are applied to the DOM.

```
[...] Wghjd7siYfkshbfbybjowLCJ1c2VycyI09u99XQ [...]
```

**BUT**

if I print the string `content` in `console.log()` , the string looks perfect! So the problem must be in `$('#list').append(content);`

**Note**

1) The function `exampleGet()` is wrapped into `$(document).ready(function(){[...]})` into a `<script>` in my HTML page.

2) I am testing with the PHP built-in server (first time I use it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in html use

```
<ul id="list">
```

instead of

```
<ul id="#list">
```

Comment: Didn't notice......thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `id=#list` to `id=list`

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:0;">     
    <ul id="list">     
    </ul>
</div>
```